# About this regular expression (?<=\d)\d{4}

Tags: regex

I use `(?<=\d)\d{4}` to match `1234567890`, the result is `2345 6789`. 
Why it's not `2345 7890`?

In the second match, it starts from 6 and 6 is matched by `(?<=\d)`, so I think the result is `7890` rather than `6789`.

Besides, how about using `((?<=\d)\d{3})+` match `1234567890`?

Comment: The '5' is the digit it is skipping when matching the second time.

Answer (score 3):

Look behinds are non consuming, so the `5` is being "reused" in the second match (even though the first match consumed it).

If you want to start at `6`, consume but don't capture:

```
\d(\d{4})
```

And use group 1, or if your regex engine supports it, use a negative look behind for `\G`, which is the end of the previous match:

```
(?!\G)(?<=\d)\d{4}
```

See a [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/KyGf3duLKp).

Answer (score 0):

`(?<=\d)` is **Zero-Length Assertion**, assertions **do not** consume characters in the string, but only assert whether a match is possible or not.

Answer (score 0):

It matches this way as the first match finishes at 5 so the next group can be matched from 6. `(?<=\d)` matches 5 in this case and the match is on 6789, starting with 6.

`(?<=\d)` doesn't belong to the match, it doesn't consume a character,  it's just asserting what is in front of the match.

Answer (score 0):

```
(?<=\d)\d{4}
```

`?<=` `Lookbehind.` Makes sure a digit precedes the text to be matched.

What text are we matching ? `d{4}` So, Meaning is match those 4 digits which are preceded by one digit.

In `1234567890` such a match is `2345` as it is preceded by `1` Now we have got one match and the string to be matched still is `1234567890` Now checking the regex condition will again tell to find group of four digits which has a prefix as a digit. Since `2345` has already been matched, the next successful match is `6789` which is preceded by `5` satisfying the regex conditions.

Coming to `(?<=\d)\d{3}` it does the same thing as before only it makes a group of 3. Editing this regex to get the one mentioned by you, we add the whole thing in a capture group. `((?<=\d)\d{3})` and say `one or more of this` `((?<=\d)\d{3})+`. A repeated capturing group will only capture the last iteration.

So `890` is returned as a match.